# python- behave: generate step functionality throws list index out of range

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-behave

this is my first question here, so any tips on improvement on that are welcome :)

I am figuring out how to write tests using: Sublime Text 3, python, and behave.

What works now is that my feature file is recognised: has all the right colours, as far as I can tell.

Now next I want to generate step functions. The desired behaviour is the that when I when I do so (right clicking on a function==> generate step function, or through the command palette, it opens a popup where I can specify that I want it to create a new file, and then creates that file.

The error I get is:
When I do, it does nothing except throw some exception in the console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "behave_toolkit.commands.highlight_unimplemented_steps in /Users/chai/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Behave Toolkit.sublime-package", line 18, in run_async
    File "behave_toolkit.mixins.steps in /Users/chai/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Behave Toolkit.sublime-package", line 50, in get_unimplemented_steps
    File "behave_toolkit.mixins.steps in /Users/chai/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Behave Toolkit.sublime-package", line 82, in _get_step_data
    File "behave_toolkit.behave_command in /Users/chai/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Behave Toolkit.sublime-package", line 27, in behave
    File "behave_toolkit.behave_command in /Users/chai/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Behave Toolkit.sublime-package", line 73, in _launch_process
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried some suggestions about defining a path to behave in package settings but that did not help.

I am not very experienced with these things, so any answer with details would be very welcome.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I edited the Q, hopefully it is a bit clearer now. Maybe I threw you off with the title suggesting there'd be a function written in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Getting Started" page of the Sublime plugin Behave Toolkit's [documentation](http://behavetoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html), the very first thing it talks about is setting up your project's directory, *then opening it in Sublime.* You are getting this error because the file(s) you are editing do(es) not belong to a [Sublime project](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects). This in turn is causing an error on [this line of the code](https://github.com/mixxorz/BehaveToolkit/blob/master/behave_toolkit/behave_command.py#L73), which throws an **`IndexError`** because `view.window().folders()[0]` is looking for the first folder present in the project (it returns a list of the folders associated with the project), which in your case does not exist.

This error is not caught, propagates, and eventually leads to the traceback you put in your question. IMO this is not a very good example of plugin programming, both because there is no error handling, and because the plugin assumes that a project (which has to have at least one folder) is active. A better method would be to abstract this line into a function which contains the error checking and a method of warning the user upon invocation what the problem is, instead of (relatively) silently failing.

So, the workaround is to always run this plugin in a project that contains only one folder, as if you have multiple folders, the plugin will by default choose the first one in the list (the zeroth element).

---

### Follow up

I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/mixxorz/BehaveToolkit/issues/17) and a [pull request](https://github.com/mixxorz/BehaveToolkit/pull/18) to fix this issue. Hopefully it will get merged and pushed out fairly quickly. If you want to use it right away, here's how:

Open the Command Palette and select `Package Control: Disable Package`, then scroll down and select `Behave Toolkit`. Now, close Sublime. Next, on the command line (assuming you have git installed and on your path), change to your `Packages` folder, which is the one opened in your operating system's file manager when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/MattDMo/BehaveToolkit.git
cd BehaveToolkit
git checkout -b issue-17
```

You can now restart Sublime, and my version of the plugin will become active. Please keep in mind that since it was installed manually, it will not be automatically updated by Package Control. Keep an eye on the Package Control page for [`Behave Toolkit`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Behave%20Toolkit) and the `MODIFIED` field on the left side at the top under `Details`. If it updates, open your user preferences (**`Preferences → Settings—User`**) and modify the `"Behave Toolkit"` line in `"ignored_packages"` to `"BehaveToolkit"` (i.e., remove the space). Save the file, and the cloned directory in `Packages` will be ignored, while the Package Control-installed version will not. Finally, you'll need to open the Command Palette and select `Package Control: Upgrade Package → Behave Toolkit` to get the latest version.

Good luck!